# C# unit test, how to test greater than

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

In C# how can I unit test a greater than condition?

I.e., if record count is greater than 5 the test succeeds.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```cs
int actualcount = target.GetCompanyEmployees().Count
Assert. ?
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
Assert.IsTrue(actualCount > 5, "The actualCount was not greater than five");
```

Comment: But it's best to put a message so that you know why the test failed:  Assert.IsTrue(actualCount > 5, "The actualCount was not greater than five");

Comment: @McKay: I personally find that a wasted effort. If the test fails, I'm going to look at its code anyway, so it wouldn't save much time *even when it fails* and the majority of assertions are never going to fail after the first check-in IME.

Comment: Well, frequently, I write tests in a manner that the test code will be run for a bunch of different tests. So while I will look at the code, I don't always look at the code that does the assertions, because they're not always close together.

Answer (score 22):

It depends on which testing framework you're using.

For xUnit.net:

`Assert.True(actualCount > 5, "Expected actualCount to be greater than 5.");`

For NUnit:

`Assert.Greater(actualCount, 5);`; however, the new syntax

`Assert.That(actualCount, Is.GreaterThan(5));` is encouraged.

For MSTest:

`Assert.IsTrue(actualCount > 5, "Expected actualCount to be greater than 5.");`

Answer (score 16):

The right way to do this when using **nUnit** is:

```
Assert.That(actualcount , Is.GreaterThan(5));
```

Comment: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert' does not contain a definition for 'That'. in VS 2012.

Comment: If you're more inclined to use the classic assert style for NUnit, another option is `Assert.Greater(actualcount, 5);`

Answer (score 9):

xUnit: if you know upper bound (=100 in example), you can use:

```
Assert.InRange(actualCount, 5, 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

A generic solution that can be used with any comparable type:

```
public static T ShouldBeGreaterThan<T>(this T actual, T expected, string message = null)
    where T: IComparable
{
    Assert.IsTrue(actual.CompareTo(expected) > 0, message);
    return actual;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in XUnit it's:

```
    [Fact]
    public void ItShouldReturnErrorCountGreaterThanZero()
    {
        Assert.True(_model.ErrorCount > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`actualCount.Should().BeGreaterThan(5);`

Comment: Looks good, this is Extension Method of ? what namespace to define?

Comment: This is only good for FluentAssertions, but as @ShloEmi told NKnusperer, good tip for those using it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers, you can always have a helper class:

```cs
public static class AssertHelper
{
    public static void Greater(int arg1, int arg2, string message = null)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(arg1 > arg2, message);
    }

    public static void NotZero(int number, string message = null)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(number != 0, message);
    }

    public static void NotNull(object obj, string message = null)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(obj != null, message);
    }

    public static void IsNotEmpty(string str, string message = null)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(str != string.Empty, message);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Usage:

```cs
AssertHelper.Greater(n1,n2)
```